# How to left-adjust display-mode MathJax. Or is it not feasible?

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a way to align MathJax display-mode expressions on the left margin?

Comment: What would make display-mode preferable to math-mode at the beginning of a line/paragraph?

Comment: @hardmath \ In answer to your question: There are certain differences in the way "display" renders certain mathematical notations -- e.g., summation -- in distinction to the same mathematical notation as rendered by "in-line." I do not do internet-related except on my 'phone, and I prefer a narrower field of vision.

Comment: Unfortunately, the userscript will not help you on the phone: mobile browsers still don't support them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a [userscript that I wrote](https://github.com/normalhuman/Userscripts/blob/master/left-aligned-formulas.user.js). Assuming you have a script manager (Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey) installed in your browser, clicking `Raw` button in Github interface will prompt for userscript installation.

The script is very simple:

```
if (MathJax) {
  MathJax.Hub.Config({displayAlign: "left"});
  MathJax.Hub.Rerender();
}
```

---

If instead of changing the appearance of *all* formulas on *your* computer, you want to change the appearance of *your* formula on *all* computers, then replace `$$...$$` with `$\displaystyle ...$` and put the latter into its own paragraph (surrounding with blank lines). For example, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
becomes

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$